# Creating a dynamic button in a separate activity

Tags: java, android

I am working on a restaurant automation application in android studios. In my MenuActivity where orders are placed, I would like to create buttons each time an order is placed in a different activity called ChefActivity. The idea is that when the  Place Order button is clicked in the MenuActivity, a button will appear in the ChefActivity so the chef can click that button to view the order. Is there a way to dynamically create a button in one activity to then display in another activity? I have done much research on this and have no been able to find much helpful information. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should to use Preferences or SQLlite to store information, and when you switch activities just read from them, it's looks like, you click on button in 1st activity, write it to database, and then when you start 2nd activity, just read from database and place data to button.